# laravel model factory override default state

Tags: php, laravel, factory

Is it possible to override the defaults of a factory without using states?

I use a tool that generates the factories from my models, but I would like to modify some attributes. I know that I can use

```
$factory->state(\App\User::class, 'moderator', function ...
```

but I would like to do it without depending on specifying the state with every model creation. So something like

```
$factory->state(\App\User::class, 'default', function ...
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more ??

Answer (score 2):

What you define in the factory is the default behaviour, for example

```
$factory->define(App\User::class, function(Faker $faker) {
    return [
        ...
        'name' => 'Jon Snow',
        ...
    ];
});
```

You can override this default behaviour with a state, for example

```
$factory->state(App\User::class, 'bad-guy', function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'name' => 'Night King'
    ]
};
```

And the last override you can do, is when you want to create that instance, for example

```
$jonSnow = factory(App\User::class)->create();

$nightKing = factory(App\User::class)->states('bad-guy')->create(); 

$samTarly = factory(App\User::class)->create([
    'name' => 'Sam Tarly'
]);
```

Comment: The tool I mentioned generates the first case and overwrites the existing factory definition. I therefore want to have an override that is applied by default so I can customize the tools output. I.e. I would like a state that is applied by default when I call factory()->create()

Comment: And why you can't override the tool-generated ones? Why are you using that tool if you want to override it anyways? Does that tool have any option to configure overrides?

Comment: I use it to have automatic defaults based on the column type in the database. Unfortunately I cannot change the tool. But I found another solution. I now have a create function that automatically applies a state named default. I use this function instead of calling the factory directly

Comment: Valar Morghulis